# How to declare string correctly for uploading to Firebase?

Tags: android, string, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to connect an app to a FireBase database and so far I have managed to do it by following [this example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TLyF7eBDlqI). It woks fine, but when I am trying to add new strings to the database, it doesn't work. I am guessing that I am not declaring the string correctly, therefore I would like to ask where am I doing wrong?

So far the code has a MainActivity (I wrote `//Here` as comment where I add the info about the string):

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private RecyclerView mPostRV;
  private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter < Post, PostViewHolder > mPostAdapter;
  private DatabaseReference mPostRef;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    initialiseScreen();

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        sendPostToFirebase();
      }
    });
  }

  private void sendPostToFirebase() {
    Post post = new Post();
    String UID = Utils.getUID();

    post.setHeadline("Headline"); //HERE
    post.setUID(UID);
    post.setNumLikes(0);
    post.setImageUrl("gs://something_something.jpg");
    mPostRef.child(UID).setValue(post);
  }

  private void initialiseScreen() {
    mPostRV = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.post_rv);
    mPostRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
    mPostRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.POSTS);
    setupAdaptater();
    mPostRV.setAdapter(mPostAdapter);
  }

  private void setupAdaptater() {
    mPostAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter < Post, PostViewHolder > (
      Post.class,
      R.layout.item_layout_post,
      PostViewHolder.class,
      mPostRef
    ) {
      @Override
      protected void populateViewHolder(PostViewHolder viewHolder, final Post model, int position) {
        StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(model.getImageUrl());
        Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
          .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
          .load(storageReference)
          .into(viewHolder.postIV);

        viewHolder.setNumLikes(model.getNumLikes());
        viewHolder.postLikeIV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
            updateNumLikes(model.getUID());
          }
        });
      }
    };
  }

  private void updateNumLikes(String uid) {
    mPostRef.child(uid).child(Constants.NUM_LIKES)
      .runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
          long num = (long) mutableData.getValue();
          num++;
          mutableData.setValue(num);
          return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }
      });
  }

  public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView postIV;
    public ImageView postLikeIV;
    public TextView numLikesIV;
    public TextView postHeadline; //HERE

    public PostViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);
      postIV = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_iv);
      postLikeIV = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.like_iv);
      numLikesIV = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.num_likes_tv);
      postHeadline = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.headline_event); //HERE
    }

    public void setPostImage(String url) {
      StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(url);
    }

    public void setHeadline(String headline) { //HERE
      postHeadline.setText(String.valueOf(headline)); //HERE
    }

    public void setNumLikes(long num) {
      numLikesIV.setText(String.valueOf(num));
    }
  }

}
```

And a class called Post

```js
public class Post {
  private String imageUrl;
  private long numLikes;
  private String nameHeadline; //Here
  private String UID;


  public Post() {}

  public Post(String imageUrl, long numLikes, String UID, String nameHeadline) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    this.numLikes = numLikes;
    this.UID = UID;
    this.nameHeadline = nameHeadline; //Here
  }

  public String getUID() {
    return UID;
  }

  public void setUID(String UID) {
    this.UID = UID;
  }

  public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
  }

  public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
  }

  public long getNumLikes() {
    return numLikes;
  }

  public void setNumLikes(long numLikes) {
    this.numLikes = numLikes;
  }

  public void setHeadline(String headline) { //Here
    this.nameHeadline = headline; //Here
  }


}
```

The code runs perfectly, but it doesn't write on the database nor reads any info about that. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added a private String. It should have public getters and setters so that Firebase can access it. I see you have a setter, but the method name doesn't match the variable name. You should rename it to:

```
public void setNameHeadline(String nameHeadline) {
    this.nameHeadline = nameHeadline;
  }

//and add a getter:
public String getNameHeadline(){
    return nameHeadline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are receiving no errors from your code, check if your Firebase Database Rules are set up appropriately. For example, if you want anyone to read and write from your database set your rules to the following:

```
// These rules give anyone, even people who are not users of your app,
// read and write access to your database

{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
 }
}
```

However if you have authentication set up, you will need to set up rules for that specifically. Check this link out for more information. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have it like that. I can write the database and download it on the app, but the "headline" String is not going up. I assume that is it because of the way I declare it in the code